# ofstream triggers breakpoint in constructor

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints, fstream

I am triggering a breakpoint in my application in the `std::fstream` class. The debug output gives no more info. I can't reproduce the problem by sectioning the class into it's own project as it works fine. Please could you suggest what the problem may be?

This is the site of the breakpoint:
[image: The fstream class basic_filebuf constructor breakpoint]

The line I am breaking on, on the callstack is ::

```
DXTBApplication.exe!std::basic_ofstream >::basic_ofstream >() Line 930 C++
```

This is the callstack:

```
msvcr120d.dll!_malloc_dbg() Unknown
msvcp120d.dll!operator new(unsigned __int64,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char *,int) Unknown
msvcp120d.dll!std::ios_base::_Init(void)    Unknown
msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::init(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *,bool) Unknown
msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *,bool)
DXTBApplication.exe!std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >() Line 930  C++
DXTBApplication.exe!CMyFile::CMyFile() Line 25  C++
DXTBApplication.exe!CFilenames::CFilenames() Line 22    C++
DXTBApplication.exe!CEngine::CEngine() Line 34  C++
DXTBApplication.exe!CApplication::CApplication(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance) Line 50 C++
DXTBApplication.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * prevInstance, char * cmdLine, int showCmd) Line 47   C++
[External Code]
```

This is my 'CMyFile' class variable declaration snippet:

```
private:
    std::ofstream m_OFS;
    std::ifstream m_IFS;
```

Instantiated in CMyFile.h  class Like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<CMyFile> m_spMyFile; // in header
m_spMyFile.reset(new CMyFile()); // in implementation - constructor
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**
This is how I assign the fstream from within `CMyFile::OpenOutput(const std::string& sFilename, unsigned int uiIOFlags)`

```
m_OFS = std::ofstream(sFilename.c_str(), uiIOFlags); //std::ios_base::binary);
```

Comment: Streams cannot be copied or assigned to.  If they are members of your class and your class is copied then that will fail.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Not copy-assigned to, but still move-assigned to.

Comment: You're probably corrupting the heap somewhere else and this allocation is the first place to discover that.  What does the complete constructor for `CMyFile` look like?

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, great stuff. The callstack shows that I am breaking before any supposed copying or assigning. Edited to show how I assign the fstreams is then accessed through the ms. The class is housed in a boost::shared_ptr and instantiated within CFilenames::CFilenames() constructor with a **new** straight into the smart pointer: 'm_spMyFile.reset(new CMyFile());'. CFilenames does no copying or assigning after that within itself.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The constructor for CMyFile is empty. They all are empty except for CApplication which only calls new for CEngine into a smart pointer and CEngine which sets the g_pEngine global variable to CEngine's this pointer.

Comment: Update: Instead of creating the CFilenames on the stack, which creates CMyFile, I used a smart pointer and instantiated it in the CEngine constructor. This makes the application break on the new-ing of it. So what ways are there to track down where I am corrupting the heap. I am using interfaces and wrapping them in smart pointers everywhere. Only instantiating in an Init() function.

Comment: @chris some compilers don't support move-assignment for fstreams  (not sure if OP's is such a one)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, True, I'm pretty sure libstdc++ was slow on that front.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it. In my debugging-ness I was using:

`_CrtSetBreakAlloc(###);`

Where ### = the line of code that leaks. I was using this earlier to mop up a whole host of memory leaks. Unfortunately I forgot and left the number in there and it continued to throw a break at that memory instantiation... Silly me!

I set it to `_CrtSetBreakAlloc(-1)` and everything is tickity-boo once more! Thanks for all jumping to help me though.